# Does POSIX require that `getconf V7_ENV` works?

Tags: posix, standards, gnu

POSIX [says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html):

> All of the following variables shall be supported:
>
> - [...]
> - The names of the symbolic constants used as the *name* argument of the [*confstr()*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/confstr.html) function in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017, without the _CS_ prefix.
> - [...]

And [*confstr()*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/confstr.html) lists, among others, the `_CS_V7_ENV` variable.

So I would expect that `getconf V7_ENV` outputs the value of the `_CS_V7_ENV` configuration variable (`POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` on GNU). But the actual output is `` getconf: Unrecognized variable `V7_ENV' ``.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might be missing the *without the _CS_ prefix* from your quote. `_CS_V7_ENV` does have the `_CS_` prefix, so that suggests that it wouldn't be found.

Comment: @ShaneBishop All of these variables have the `_CS_` prefix. I am interpreting the standard as saying the name shall be supplied to `getconf` without the `_CS_` prefix.

Comment: `_CS_V6_ENV` and `_CS_V7_ENV` don't even exist in the headers on FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE, so it's not surprising that it would fail there.  On Debian Buster, it is odd that `confstr()` will store `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` while `getconf` fails.  Maybe there's a suitable workaround for whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: @MemReflect I have a workaround. I'm just asking here out of curiosity.